# Is it possible to use a 558 quad-timer IC as a polyphonic synthesizer?

Tags: 555, synthesizer

As the title suggests, After looking at the pinout of the 558 IC, I've noticed that there are multiple output pins for each oscillator, so I'm wondering if there's an easy way to mix all four signals coming from each pin, and use the chip as a polyphonic synth, with the ability to control PWM, frequency, and volume for each separate oscillator?

Comment: Multiple output pins *for each* oscillator? I see just one per timer. Anyway, you can indeed mix the signals. But how do you plan to control frequency/volumes for each channel? With pots, fine. But if you plan on using a MCU as the controller, it would actually be much simpler to make the software directly compute the final waveform.

Comment: short answer No.  .... 4 analog functions are possible but hardly comparable (i.e.<<1% ) of what an inexpensive Synthesizer chip can do today.

Comment: Can you recommend an affordable synthesizer chip to me?

Answer (score 1):

The most common way of controlling frequency with the 555, 7555, and other chips in those families is by adjusting the control voltage.  On the 556, the two timer circuits each have a separate control voltage input, allowing their frequencies to be controlled independently.  On the 558, however, there is one control-voltage input which acts upon all four of the timing circuits simultaneously.

It may be possible to use the 558 as a four-voice synthesizer if one were to drive the oscillators with four separate programmable current sources.  The outputs would likely just be short pulses, however, unless one added some more complex circuitry which would reduce the linearity of the current-to-frequency conversion.  While using a 558 as a four-voice synthesizer in that scenario would certainly be possible, the circuitry required to support its use in such a role would likely exceed what would be required to build a synthesizer via other means.